# free is not freeing up my memory despite no errors happening

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a function that allocates a string into a buffer inside a structure.

My problem is that the memory is not being deallocated despite no errors occuring.

I look in Process Hacker and see my private byte usage going from 700KB to over 20MB (I am running the code inside a loop for fuzzing, but it is not the fuzz data causing it as I have checked).

I am unfortunately unable to reproduce it in a small example despite the code being exactly the same except for the lack of critical sections and error checking (At least from what I can see)

So my question is, what could be causing this and what should I look for? I cannot use Valgrind since I use Windows.

```
struct str {
    wchar_t* buff;
    INT size;
};

void allocstr(struct str* dat, const wchar_t* str) {
    ZeroMemory(dat, sizeof(*dat));
    int len = wcslen(str);
    dat->size = sizeof(wchar_t) * len;
    dat->buff = (wchar_t*)(malloc(dat->size));
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        dat->buff[i] = str[i];
    }
}

void resizstr(struct str* dat, int news) {
    wchar_t* temp = (wchar_t*)(realloc(dat->buff, news));
    if(NULL == temp) {
        return;
    }
    dat->buff = temp;
}

void freestr(struct str* dat) {
    ZeroMemory(dat->buff, dat->size);
    free(dat->buff);
}
```

Comment: `wchar_t* temp = (wchar_t*)(realloc(dat->buff, news));` don't you have to pass `news * sizeof(wchar_t)` here?

Comment: I was calculating `news` inside of the main() function. I believe if that was an issue in my normal program, I would get a heap corruption error after attempting to free, but I am getting no errors

Comment: `free()` doesn't return the memory to the operating system, it just makes it available for use by future allocations.

Comment: That may be so, but I believe the private bytes refer to the memory currently allocated by my process. The code posted above does not increase the private byte usage